# Raising UAC shield using IsAdmin()

Tags: vb.net

I need to raise UAC shield.  I found code over net

```
 MyBase.OnLoad(e)
 If Not IsAdmin() Then
      AddShield(Me.elevateButton)
 End If
```

But it does not work.  It returns error on IsAdmin() saying "IsAdmin() is not declared"
Please advise how I can use it and how I can raise the UAC shield.

Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://wyday.com/blog/2009/using-shield-icons-uac-and-process-elevation-in-csharp-vb-net-on-windows-2000-xp-vista-and-7/) is a guide to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically indicating that the it can't can't find the definition of this function. If this function were a part of the .NET framework, you would need to determine which namespace the function belongs to. Once you knew that, you could use `Imports` to "pull in" the name space or could uses the function's name (which includes its name space). For example, to acces the .NET File object without using `Imports`, you need to use `File`'s full name (`System.IO.File`).

In this case, though, it appears that IsAdmin is not part of the .Net framework. As such, you must provide the programming code that defines `IsAdmin()`.

Just to be clear, the paragraph about name spaces does not apply only to the .NET framework; it applies to other things as well, including external DLLs that have been added as reference to the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this :

```
<DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint:="IsUserAnAdmin")> _
Public Shared Function IsUserAnAdmin() As Boolean
End Function
```

Then you can just run

```
If IsUserAnAdmin() = True Then....
```

And it will of course return False is not running with elevated priviledges.